# DynamoDB get_item to read 400kb data in milliseconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table called `events` in which i stored all `user event details`  like `product_view` ,`add_to_cart` and `product_purchase`

In this `events` table, I have some `items` whose storage capacity reached `400kb`

**Issue:**

```
        response = self._table.get_item(
            Key={
                PARTITION_KEY: <pk>,
                SORT_KEY: <sk>,
            },
            ConsistentRead=False,
        )
```

when I want to use `dynamodb get_item` method to access the `item(400kb)`, it is taking around `5 seconds` to return the result.

**I already used DAX**

**Goal**

**I want to read `400kb` item in less than a 1 second.**

**Important information:**

The data in the `dynamodb` will be stored in this format

```
{
 "partition_key": "user_id1111",
 "sort_key": "version_1",
 "attributes": {
  "events": [
   {
    "t": "1614712316",  
    "a": "product_view",   
    "i": "1275"
   },
   {
    "t": "1614712316",  
    "a": "product_add",   
    "i": "1275"
   },
   {
    "t": "1614712316",  
    "a": "product_purchase",   
    "i": "1275"
   },
    ...

  ]
 }
}
```

- `t` is a timestamp
- `a` may be `product_view`,`product_add`,`product_purchase`
- `i` is the product_id

If you see above item `events` is a list and it will be appended by new events.

I have an item which is `400kb` with number of events in the `events` list

I wrote some script to measure the time and the results are given below

```py
import boto3
import datetime

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('events')

pk = f"user_id1111"
sk = f"version_1"


t_load_start = datetime.datetime.now()


response = table.get_item(
    Key={
        "partition_key": pk,
        "sort_key": sk,
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL"
)
capacity_units = response["ConsumedCapacity"]["CapacityUnits"]

t_load_end = datetime.datetime.now()
seconds = (t_load_end - t_load_start).total_seconds()

print(f"Elapsed time is::{seconds}sec and {capacity_units} capacity units")
```

This is the output I'm getting.

```
Elapsed time is::5.676799sec and 50.0 capacity units
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: You're not going to want to hear this, but I'd start reconsidering the data model. Technically 5 seconds is 5000 milliseconds, can you be more precise with the performance requirements? ;-)

Comment: @maurice, I want to get the item in less than 1 second

Comment: where is your client located? could the latency be introduced between your client and the AWS network? To be able to transfer 400 kilo-bytes in less than a second you'll need a reliable ~4 mega-bit / second internet connection which could be a factor in your experiments

Comment: @MikeDinescu, for your info, i am using `us-east-1`. The issue whatever i am experiencing is, whenever i want to read dynamodb item from local system, it is taking more time than expected(less than 1 second).

Comment: So, your local is an EC2 instance in us-east-1? Or is the ddb table in us-east-1?

Comment: Is your table using provisioned capacity or pay-per-request? If it's provisioned, what is its provisioned read capacity?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee, My dynamodb table is on `On-demand' mode.

Comment: 5 seconds isn't a reasonable measurement regardless of item size/geography; you're most likely being throttled. You can check in the 'Metrics' tab of your table in the AWS Console, see the 'Throttled read requests/events' graphs, or [check if boto3 is retrying](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#validating-retry-attempts)

Comment: Is the Lambda function definitely in the same region as the DynamoDB table? Is the Lambda running in VPC and, if so, do you have any unusual network routing?

Comment: yes, lambda function and dynamodb is there in the same region(us-east-1) and lambda function is using `vpc`. I didnt see any unusaual routing

Comment: Did you check the metrics for throttling @siva ?

Comment: in cloudwatch -metrics section, under dynamodb tab, i am seeing not seeing `throttling` metric for my table. for my table, i am seeing only `SuccessfulRequestLatency` metric.

Can you please tell me where i need to look?

Comment: In DynamoDB if you select the table, there is a metrics tab, which among others shows the "Throttled read requests". Maybe just add a screenshot of the whole tab while you're using the table and experiencing long response times.

Comment: @Maurice, I just checked it. thre is no `throttling`. I am not sure how to add the screenshot here.

Comment: You mentioned Lambda - how much memory have you assigned to your function? Network and CPU resources scale with memory - maybe try increasing that.

Comment: i am using `256mb` of memory for lambda. in my view this memory is more than enough.

Comment: Please try 1024MB, it's not about the memory, but Network and CPU.

Comment: I measured it, the Lambda function's memory is what you want to tweak. By assigning 1024MB to it, you can easily get it below 1000ms - check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66436200/6485881) for details.

Comment: @Maurice, I just increased the memory to `1024` and it seems works fine for me incase of `dynamodb-getitem`. I am just curious about `dynamodb put-item` and  `dynamodb update-item`. Do you think the issue will be there for these 2 cases also when i use `256mb`?

Comment: I don't know - try it, it's just a few clicks in the console...

Comment: got it. Thanks @Maurice for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr: Increase your functions memory to at least 1024MB, see update 2

---

I was curious, so I did some measurements. I created a script that creates a big boi item with pretty much exactly 400KB in size in a fresh table.

Then I test two reads from Python - one with the resource API and the other with the lower level client - eventually consistent reads in both cases.

Here's what I measured:

```
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.366508s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.301585s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
```

If we extrapolate from the RCUs, the item it read was about `50 * 2 * 4KB = 400 KB` in size (eventually consistent reads consume 0.5 RCUs).

I ran it a few times locally from Germany against `eu-central-1` (Frankfurt, Germany) and the highest latency I saw was about 900ms. (This is without DAX.)

**As a result of that I think you should show us how you did your measurements.**

```py
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

TABLE_NAME = "big-boi-test"
BIG_BOI_PK = "f0ba8d6c"

TABLE_RESOURCE = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE_NAME)
DDB_CLIENT = boto3.client("dynamodb")

def create_table():
    DDB_CLIENT.create_table(
        AttributeDefinitions=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "AttributeType": "S"}],
        TableName=TABLE_NAME,
        KeySchema=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "KeyType": "HASH"}],
        BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST"
    )

def create_big_boi_item() -> str:
    # based on calculations here: https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/
    template = {
        "PK": {
            "S": BIG_BOI_PK
        },
        "bigBoi": {
            "S": ""
        }
    } # This is 16 bytes

    big_boi = "X" * (1024 * 400 - 16)
    template["bigBoi"]["S"] = big_boi
    return template

def store_big_boi():
    big_bio = create_big_boi_item()

    DDB_CLIENT.put_item(
        Item=big_bio,
        TableName=TABLE_NAME
    )

def get_big_boi_with_table_resource():

    start = datetime.now()
    response = TABLE_RESOURCE.get_item(
        Key={"PK": BIG_BOI_PK},
        ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL"
    )
    end = datetime.now()
    seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()
    capacity_units = response["ConsumedCapacity"]["CapacityUnits"]

    print(f"Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took {seconds}s and consumed {capacity_units} RCUs")

def get_big_boi_with_client():

    start = datetime.now()
    response = DDB_CLIENT.get_item(
        Key={"PK": {"S": BIG_BOI_PK}},
        ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL",
        TableName=TABLE_NAME
    )
    end = datetime.now()
    seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()
    capacity_units = response["ConsumedCapacity"]["CapacityUnits"]

    print(f"Reading Big Boi from a Client took {seconds}s and consumed {capacity_units} RCUs")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create_table()
    # store_big_boi()
    get_big_boi_with_table_resource()
    get_big_boi_with_client()
```

### Update

I did the same measurements again with an item that looks more like the one you're using, I'm still below 1000ms on average no matter which way I request them:

```
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 1.492829s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.871583s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.857513s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.769432s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.690172s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.670099s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.633489s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.605999s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.598635s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took 0.606553s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 1.66636s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.921605s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.831735s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.707082s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.668602s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.648401s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.5695s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.592073s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.611436s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Reading Big Boi from a Client took 0.553827s and consumed 50.0 RCUs
Average latency over 10 requests with the table resource: 0.7796304s
Average latency over 10 requests with the client: 0.7770621s
```

This is what the item looks like:

[image]
[image]

Here is the full test-script for you to verify:

```py
import statistics
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

TABLE_NAME = "big-boi-test"
BIG_BOI_PK = "NestedBoi"

TABLE_RESOURCE = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE_NAME)
DDB_CLIENT = boto3.client("dynamodb")

def create_table():
    DDB_CLIENT.create_table(
        AttributeDefinitions=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "AttributeType": "S"}],
        TableName=TABLE_NAME,
        KeySchema=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "KeyType": "HASH"}],
        BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST"
    )

def create_big_boi_item() -> str:
    # based on calculations here: https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/
    template = {
        "PK": {
            "S": "NestedBoi"
        },
        "bigBoiContainer": {
            "M": {
            "bigBoiList": {
                "L": [
                
                ]
            }
            }
        }
    } # 43 bytes

    item = {
        "M": {
        "t": {
            "S": "1614712316"
        },
        "a": {
            "S": "product_view"
        },
        "i": {
            "S": "1275"
        }
        }
    }  # 36 bytes

    number_of_items = int((1024 * 400 - 43) / 36)

    for _ in range(number_of_items):
        template["bigBoiContainer"]["M"]["bigBoiList"]["L"].append(item)

    return template

def store_big_boi():
    big_bio = create_big_boi_item()

    DDB_CLIENT.put_item(
        Item=big_bio,
        TableName=TABLE_NAME
    )

def get_big_boi_with_table_resource():

    start = datetime.now()
    response = TABLE_RESOURCE.get_item(
        Key={"PK": BIG_BOI_PK},
        ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL"
    )
    end = datetime.now()
    seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()
    capacity_units = response["ConsumedCapacity"]["CapacityUnits"]

    print(f"Reading Big Boi from a Table Resource took {seconds}s and consumed {capacity_units} RCUs")

    return seconds

def get_big_boi_with_client():

    start = datetime.now()
    response = DDB_CLIENT.get_item(
        Key={"PK": {"S": BIG_BOI_PK}},
        ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL",
        TableName=TABLE_NAME
    )
    end = datetime.now()
    seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()
    capacity_units = response["ConsumedCapacity"]["CapacityUnits"]

    print(f"Reading Big Boi from a Client took {seconds}s and consumed {capacity_units} RCUs")

    return seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create_table()
    # store_big_boi()

    n_experiments = 10
    experiments_with_table_resource = [get_big_boi_with_table_resource() for i in range(n_experiments)]
    experiments_with_client = [get_big_boi_with_client() for i in range(n_experiments)]
    print(f"Average latency over {n_experiments} requests with the table resource: {statistics.mean(experiments_with_table_resource)}s")
    print(f"Average latency over {n_experiments} requests with the client: {statistics.mean(experiments_with_client)}s")
```

If I increase n_experiments, it tends to get even faster, probably because DDB caches internally.

**Still: can't reproduce.**

---

### Update 2

After learning you're running Lambda functions, I ran the tests again inside of Lambda with different memory configurations.

| Memory | n_experiments | average time with resource | average time with client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 128MB | 10 | 6.28s | 5.06s |
| 256MB | 10 | 3.26s | 2.61s |
| 512MB | 10 | 1.62s | 1.33s |
| 1024MB | 10 | 0.84s | 0.68s |
| 2048MB | 10 | 0.52s | 0.43s |
| 4096MB | 10 | 0.51s | 0.41s |

As mentioned in the comments, CPU and Network performance scale with the amount of Memory you assign to a function.
You can solve your problem by throwing money at it :-)

Comment: I just added my script to identify the latency and added a snapshot of the `dynamodb item` in the question section. Please check it

Comment: my dynamodb table is there in  `us-east-1(N.Virginia)`

Comment: I updated my answer to check for an item that is more similar to your nested data structure - still can't reproduce. Did you check the metrics for throttling?

Comment: Fantastic stuff.  I think the lesson learned here is that lambda performance scales with memory.  Even if the memory seems sufficient, tweaking the value can lead to substantial performance improvements.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a few issues.  The first issue is that you're running up against the 400kb item size limitation.  Although you don't say this is an issue, it may be worth revisiting your data model so you can store more event data.

The performance issue is unlikely related to your data model.  The `get_item` operation should have an average latency in single-digit milliseconds, especially since you're specifying an eventually consistent read.  Something else is going on here.

How are you testing and measuring the performance of this operation?

The AWS docs have a few suggestions from the [about troubleshooting high latency DynamoDB operations](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-high-latency/) that may be useful.

Comment: Basically there is a 400kb issue in my dynamodb table. so I am accessing`item` and then calculating the size and then truncating the 400kb item into 200kb item.

Todo this task, I am first accessing dynamodb item using `get_item` but `get_item` is taking around `5` seconds to get the item

Comment: I am calculating time of operation using `python's` - `datetime` module

Comment: Are you logging to Cloudwatch?  I'm wondering if the actual request for DDB is taking 5 seconds, or if there is something else taking up all that time.  Check out the DynamoDB metrics in Cloudwatch to see if it's really DDB that's taking that long: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html

Comment: I just added a snapshot of the my `Dynamo DB` item in the question section, please check it